# Migrate EJB 2.1 from WebSphere 6.1 to JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, websphere

I'm trying to migrate from WS 6.1 to JBoss EAP 6.1. I'm having a hard time trying to make the EJB 2.1 working in JBoss 6.1.

(Note : @GatewayEjbJndiName@ is replaced at compile time by ant.)

This was the original ejb-jar.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">
    <display-name>ServerGateway</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session id="Session_gateway">
            <display-name>GatewayEJBSB</display-name>
            <ejb-name>@GatewayEjbJndiName@</ejb-name>
            <home>ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemoteHome</home>
            <remote>ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemote</remote>
            <ejb-class>ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <container-transaction>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>@GatewayEjbJndiName@</ejb-name>
                <method-name>*</method-name>
            </method>
            <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

This is (after many hours of research) what i came up for JBoss EAP 6.1 (ejb-jar.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">
    <display-name>ServerGateway</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session id="Session_gateway">
            <display-name>GatewayEJBSB</display-name>
            <ejb-name>@GatewayEjbJndiName@</ejb-name>
            <home>ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemoteHome</home>
            <remote>ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemote</remote>
            <ejb-class>ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <ejb-ref>
                <ejb-ref-name>ejb/projectGatewayEJB</ejb-ref-name>
                <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
                <home>ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemoteHome</home>
                <remote>ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemote</remote>
            </ejb-ref>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <container-transaction>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>@GatewayEjbJndiName@</ejb-name>
                <method-name>*</method-name>
            </method>
            <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

But every time is tried to start the JBoss server i have this error :

```
[org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named ProjectGatewayEJB in deployment unit subdeployment "GatewayEJBClientProject.jar" of deployment "Project.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/Project/GatewayEJBClientProject/ProjectGatewayEJB!ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemote
    java:app/GatewayEJBClientProject/ProjectGatewayEJB!ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemote
    java:module/ProjectGatewayEJB!ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemote
    java:jboss/exported/Project/GatewayEJBClientProject/ProjectGatewayEJB!ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemote
    java:global/Project/GatewayEJBClientProject/ProjectGatewayEJB!ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemoteHome
    java:app/GatewayEJBClientProject/ProjectGatewayEJB!ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemoteHome
    java:module/ProjectGatewayEJB!ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemoteHome
    java:jboss/exported/Project/GatewayEJBClientProject/ProjectGatewayEJB!ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemoteHome

10:54:41,858 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Project.ear"."ProjectWebApp.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Project.ear"."ProjectWebApp.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "ProjectWebApp.war" of deployment "Project.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014543: No EJB found with interface of type 'ca.company.qc.project.server.gateway.ejb.GatewayEJBRemoteHome' and name 'ServerGateway.jar#GatewayEJB' for binding java:module/env/ProjectGatewayEJBBean
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.addJndiBinding(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    ... 5 more
```

There is NO annotation anywhere in the EJBBean/EJBRemote/EJBRemoteBusiness/EJBRemoteHome classes. Because it's not supported in EJB 2.1 (for what i know).

I run the server using the "standalone-full.xml" config file. I also tried standalone-ha.xml with no success.

I really don't know what to do next..

Answer (score 0):

There is topic on the [JBoss community forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/195912?tstart=0), I hope it'll help you to resolve problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check the automated pluggable rule-based migration tool [JBoss Windup](http://windup.jboss.org). It covers EJB 2.1 to EJB 3 migration to some extent.

If you find something that is not covered, the Windup team will be happy to accept requests for enhancements at http://issues.jboss.org/WINDUPRULE.

To your question:

EJB 3 is available with `standalone.xml`, no need for `standalone-ha` which stands for High Availability, i.e. clustered solutions. `full` means full profile, as opposed to `web` profile, which is specified in Java EE 6 specification. See [Java EE 6 Web profile vs Java EE 6 Full Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239978/java-ee-6-web-profile-vs-java-ee-6-full-platform) .

I suggest to migrate to EJB 3 since Java EE 7 is here for some time and support for EJB 2.x will be dropped by most app servers.