# Java EE Web Profile vs Java EE Full Platform

Tags: jakarta-ee

What is the difference between a **Java EE Web Profile** certified server (like JOnAS) and a **Java EE Full Platform** certified server (like JBoss AS)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is different about the Java EE packages? (SDK/normal vs Web Profile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612269/what-is-different-about-the-java-ee-packages-sdk-normal-vs-web-profile)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Here is nice image which explains it. Web profile is a subset of Java EE and it's purpose is to allow developers to create more lightweight applications which can be used inside simple servlet container (like Tomcat or Jetty).

[image]

Comment: Update: Web profile has been updated. Severs components have been moved to webprofile such as JAX-RS, JAX-B etc and some new components like JSON-P have been added. Please see this document from Jakarta EE for more details: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/8/webprofile-spec-8.pdf

Answer (score 61):

## tl;dr

An app server compliant with *Jakarta EE Platform* profile **implements over a dozen more [specifications](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/)** that does an app server compliant with *Jakarta EE Web Profile*.

In other words, a *Web Profile* compliant server offers **a subset of the features** offered by a *Platform* profile compliant server:

> *Platform* profile = *Web Profile* + more stuff

## Transition, from *Oracle Corp* to *Eclipse Foundation*

In late 2017, [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation) gave responsibility for [Java EE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation). Future versions after Java EE 8 will be known as [*Eclipse Enterprise For Java (EE4J)*](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j/). Or *Project EE4J*. Or maybe *EE.next*. Or [*Jakarta EE*](https://adtmag.com/articles/2018/02/26/java-ee-name-change-to-jakarta-ee.aspx). The branding has been changing.

### Impact of changes to Java SE

In Java SE 11, some modules are dropped. The Java EE related parts are moving to a new home at the Jakarta EE project. Others such as [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) have been offered for adoption by any interested organization. See [JEP 320](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320).

## Jakarta EE 10

[Jakarta EE 10](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-platform/jakartaee10/JakartaEE10) is being planned now (2021-09). After all the phases in the transition from Oracle Corp to Eclipse Foundation, the platform can now make progress with major improvements, new features, and pruning of undesirable features.

Version 10 is likely to involve some breaks in compatibility, in order to facilitate innovation. But nothing is yet written in stone. Get involved in the open process now if you have interests/concerns/suggestions/contributions.

[*Java SE 11*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11) will become the minimum runtime supported by Jakarta EE compatible implementations.

For more info, see:

- [*Java for the enterprise: What to expect in Jakarta EE 10*](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/java-jakartaee-cdi-ejb-jsf-tijms) by Arjan Tijms, 2021-03.
- [*Towards a Community Vision for
  Jakarta EE 10*](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2020/november/2.php) by Reza Rahman.

### *Platform Profile* in Jakarta EE 10

For an overview of proposed changes to the *Platform Profile*, see [*Define Jakarta EE Platform 10 #364*](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-platform/issues/364).

### *Core Profile* in Jakarta EE 10

Jakarta EE 10 may gain a new profile, [*Core Profile*](https://jakarta.ee/zh/specifications/coreprofile/), besides the current [*Web Profile*](https://jakarta.ee/zh/specifications/webprofile/) and (full) [*Platform Profile*](https://jakarta.ee/zh/specifications/platform/).

The Core Platform targets smaller runtimes suitable for [microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) and [ahead-of-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation). See GitHub page, [*Define Jakarta EE Core Profile 10 #387*](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-platform/issues/387).

### *Web Profile* in Jakarta EE 10

[Ivar Grimstad](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/new-java-champion-ivar-grimstad) has proposed changes to the *Web Profile* in Java EE 10 listed on [*Define Jakarta EE Web Profile 10 #363*](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-platform/issues/363).

#### Proposed new additions

- [Jakarta MVC](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mvc/) 2.1 - #381
- [Jakarta Config](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/config/) 1.0 (no plan proposed yet)
- [Jakarta Concurrency](http://%5BJakarta%20Concurrency%5D%5B8%5D) 3.0

#### Major updates

- [Jakarta Servlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/) 5.0 -> [6.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/)
- [Jakarta Expression Language](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/) 4.0 -> 5.0
- [Jakarta Standard Tag Library](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/) 2.0 -> 3.0
- Jakarta Faces 3.0 -> 4.0
- [Jakarta RESTful Web Services](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/) 3.0 -> 3.1 or 4.0
- [Jakarta Security](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/security/) 2.0 -> 3.0
- [Jakarta Authentication](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/authentication/) 2.0 -> 3.0
- [Jakarta Contexts and Dependency Injection](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/) 3.0 -> 4.0

#### Minor updates

- [Jakarta Server Pages](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/pages/) 3.0 -> [3.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/pages/3.1/)
- [Jakarta WebSocket](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/websocket/) 2.0 -> [2.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/websocket/2.1/)
- [Jakarta JSON Processing](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonp/) 2.0 -> [2.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonp/2.1/)
- [Jakarta JSON Binding](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonb/) 2.0 -> [2.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonb/2.1/)
- [Jakarta Persistence](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/) 3.0 -> [3.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/)

#### No updates

- Jakarta Debugging Support for Other Languages 2.0
- Jakarta Annotations 2.0
- Jakarta Enterprise Beans 4.0 Lite
- Jakarta Transactions 2.0
- Jakarta Bean Validation 3.0
- Jakarta Managed Beans 2.0
- Jakarta Interceptors 2.0
- Jakarta Dependency Injection 2.0

## Jakarta EE 9.1

[Jakarta EE 9.1](https://jakarta.ee/release/9.1/) was [released 2021-05](https://jakarta.ee/news/jakarta-ee-9-1-released/).

See:

- Full platform project page: [*Jakarta EE Platform 9.1*](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jakartaee-platform/releases/9.1)
- [*Web Profile 9.1* project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jakartaee-platform/releases/web-profile-9.1/plan) page.

Version 9.1 makes Jakarta EE compatible with [Java SE 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11). This is the only significant change. Few API changes, nothing incompatible. Version 9.1 is functionally equivalent to Jakarta EE 9.

## Jakarta EE 9

[*Jakarta EE Platform 9*](https://jakarta.ee/release/9/) was [released 2020-12](https://jakarta.ee/news/jakarta-ee-9-released/).

The focus is on removing the trademarked *Java* name from the various specifications. This includes moving to a new package name of `jakarta.*`. In that one specific sense, this is a breaking release, as projects must be updated to the new package to run on EE 9 servers. After changing package name, existing apps will run well with few or no other changes.

To quote the [Jakarta EE 9 Release Plan](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-platform/jakartaee9/JakartaEE9ReleasePlan) page:

> The goal of the Jakarta EE 9 release is to deliver a set of specifications functionally similar to Jakarta EE 8 but in the new Jakarta EE 9 namespace `jakarta.*`.

> In addition, the Jakarta EE 9 release removes specifications from Jakarta EE 8 that were old, optional, or deprecated in order to reduce the surface area of the APIs to ensure that it is easier for new vendors to enter the ecosystem – as well as reduce the burden on implementation, migration, and maintenance of these old APIs.

> Predominantly, the project team sees Jakarta EE 9 as a tooling release…

Even though you will likely be able to expect upward compatibility in behavior, the naming changes means version 9 and later are *not* be a drop-in binary replacement. Not the end of the world. This may mean as little as you changing the `import` package names in your various class files. Read [this](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/05/end-of-javax-package) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/transitioning-jakarta-ee-to-the-jakarta-namespace) for details and links.

## Jakarta EE 8

[*Jakarta EE Platform 8*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/) is practically identical to *Java EE 8*.

As part of the transition from Oracle, the Eclipse team re-released Java EE 8 as *Jakarta EE 8* using their new infrastructure for housing code and making builds. Same EE behavior, same internal naming and package structure. So the issues discussed below about Java EE Web Profile versus Java EE Full Platform still apply.

Jakarta EE 8 uses the `javax.*` package naming, borrowed from Oracle Corp. Version 9 changes the package naming to `jakarta.*`.

## Java EE 8

[Java EE 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history) was released 2017. See [history of versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history).

See [JSR 366: Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 8 (Java EE 8) Specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=366) for details.

Java EE is a superset of [Java Standard Edition (Java SE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition). Any Java EE 8 implementation is also an implementation of Java SE 8 or later.

See a [list of Java EE 8 technologies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) published by Oracle, with links to JSRs and specs.

### All profiles

The following technologies are required to be present in all Java EE profiles:

> • [Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Standard_Edition) version [8 (or later)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)

> • Resource and component lifecycle annotations defined by the Common
> Annotations specification (Resource, Resources, PostConstruct, PreDestroy)

> • [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) “java:” naming context

> • Java Transaction API (JTA)

### Web Profile

The [Web Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_profile) is a specific subset of the full Java EE platform, focusing on commonly used elements. Implemented by products such as [*Apache TomEE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_TomEE) or nearly so with [*Eclipse Jetty* plus add-ons](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-javaee.html).

> • Base level items required by all Java EE profiles ( listed above: Java SE 8, lifecycle annotations, JNDI `java:` context, and JTA )

> • Servlet 4.0 ([JSR 369](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr369/index.html))

> • JavaServer Pages (JSP) 2.3

> • Expression Language (EL) 3.0 ([JSR 341](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=341))

> • Debugging Support for Other Languages (JSR-45) 1.0

> • Standard Tag Library for JavaServer Pages (JSTL) 1.2

> • JavaServer Faces (JSF) 2.3 ([JSR 372](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=372))

> • Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) 2.1

> • Java API for WebSocket (WebSocket) 1.1 ([JSR 356](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356))

> • Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P) 1.1 ([JSR 374](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374))

> • Java API for JSON Binding (JSON-B) 1.0 ([JSR 367](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367))

> • Common Annotations for the Java Platform (JSR-250) 1.3 • Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) 3.2 Lite

> • Java Transaction API (JTA) 1.2

> • Java Persistence API (JPA) 2.2

> • [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org) 2.0 ([JSR 380](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=380))

> • Managed Beans 1.0

> • Interceptors 1.2

> • Contexts and Dependency Injection for the Java EE Platform 2.0

> • Dependency Injection for Java 1.0

> • Java EE Security API 1.0

> • Java Authentication Service Provider Interface for Containers (JASPIC) 1.1

## Servlet-oriented (*Tomcat* & *Jetty*)

As a lighter alternative to using a  Web Profile implementation, you could start with a Java [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet)/[JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages) implementation such as [*Apache Tomcat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) or [*Eclipse Jetty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)). While not official as a profile, this approach is very popular. Sometimes known as a [*web container*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container).

- [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server)
- [Servlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/)
- [JavaServer Pages (JSP)](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/pages/)
- [Expression Language (EL)](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/)
- [Standard Tag Library](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/)
- [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)
- [JNDI server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface)

IMHO, this should have long ago been formalized as a JavaEE / Jakarta EE profile. Given the huge popularity of Tomcat & Jetty, the need and benefit of a formal profile seems obvious to me.

When using this setup, you may selectively add independent libraries to benefit selectively from the various Java EE technologies. For example, for my own work building web apps using [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow), I use Java SE with [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat). Sometimes I add a [*Bean Validation*](http://beanvalidation.org) implementation library manually as that is all I need from the Java EE list of technologies.

A few of the Jakarta EE specifications have been re-engineered to work directly with Java SE based apps without a Jakarta EE server. And more such re-engineering is being planned. Implementations of such specs could be used with Tomcat or Jetty.

Of course, at some point rather than keeping adding more Jakarta EE oriented libraries to your Tomcat/Jetty project, it might make more sense to just switch to using a server compliant with one of the wider Jakarta EE profiles.

### Full Java EE

The following technologies are required:

> • All the items in Web Profile

> • EJB 3.2 (except for EJB entity beans and associated EJBQL, which have been made optional)

> • JMS 2.0

> • JavaMail 1.6

> • Connector 1.7

> • WebServices 1.4

> • Concurrency Utilities 1.0

> • Batch1.0

> • Java EE Management 1.1

> • JACC 1.5

> • JSP Debugging 1.0

> • Web Services Metadata 2.1

The following technologies are optional:

> • EJB 3.2 and earlier entity beans and associated EJB QL

> • JAX-RPC 1.1

> • JAXR 1.0

> • Java EE Deployment 1.2

## Diagram

Here is a diagram to show the nested groups of requirements.

[image: diagram of nested groups of various technologies required by Java SE 8, web containers, Java EE 8 Web Profile, Java EE 8 Required, and Java EE 8 Optional]

The list above this diagram may be more accurate; this diagram has not been double-checked.

Comment: Note that both Tomcat and Jetty out of the box contain the Servlet Container Profile of JASPIC, which is itself a subset of full JASPIC (a little like EJB-lite)

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: @ArjanTijms Can you provide links to references or documentation about Servlet Container Profile of JASPIC? I would like to incorporate that info into the Answer.

Comment: The source of the Servlet Container Profile is here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/authentication/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/servlet-container-profile.adoc

The official (milestone) rendered version is here: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/authentication/2.0/authentication-spec-2.0-SNAPSHOT.html#a365

Thanks for this great answer here :)

Comment: good answer, thanks! FYI, there is a link to the Eclipse homepage of web profile specification including 8, 9, 9.1 and 10: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/

Answer (score 6):

The [Java EE 6 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr316/index.html) (JSR 316) contains the following lists:

### Full Java EE Product Requirements

> The following technologies are required:
>
> - EJB 3.1
> - Servlet 3.0
> - JSP 2.2
> - EL 2.2
> - JMS 1.1
> - JTA 1.1
> - JavaMail 1.4
> - Connector 1.6
> - Web Services 1.3
> - JAX-RPC 1.1
> - JAX-WS 2.2
> - JAX-RS 1.1
> - JAXB 2.2
> - JAXR 1.0
> - Java EE Management 1.1
> - Java EE Deployment 1.2
> - JACC 1.4
> - JASPIC 1.0
> - JSP Debugging 1.0
> - JSTL 1.2
> - Web Services Metadata 2.1
> - JSF 2.0
> - Common Annotations 1.1
> - Java Persistence 2.0
> - Bean Validation 1.0
> - Managed Beans 1.0
> - Contexts and Dependency Injection for Java EE 1.0
> - Dependency Injection for Java 1.0
>
> There are no optional technologies.

### Web Profile Definition

> The following technologies are required components of the Web Profile:
>
> - Servlet 3.0
> - JavaServer Pages (JSP) 2.2
> - Expression Language (EL) 2.2
> - Debugging Support for Other Languages (JSR-45) 1.0
> - Standard Tag Library for JavaServer Pages (JSTL) 1.2
> - JavaServer Faces (JSF) 2.0
> - Common Annotations for theJava Platform (JSR-250) 1.1
> - Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) 3.1 Lite
> - Java Transaction API (JTA) 1.1
> - Java Persistence API (JPA) 2.0
> - Bean Validation 1.0
> - Managed Beans 1.0
> - Interceptors 1.1
> - Contexts and Dependency Injection for the Java EE Platform 1.0
> - Dependency Injection for Java 1.06
>
> There are no optional components in the Web Profile.

For Java EE 7, there is a [list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) of all EE technologies, also showing which are included in the Web Profile. Some technologies formerly available only in the Full Profile are now included in the Web Profile, such as JAX-RS.

Answer (score 2):

This image helped me a lot to understand the differences in Jakarta EE 10.

[image]

I got it from https://jakarta.ee/release/10/