# What's the difference between a Java EE application and a Web application in IntelliJ?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, intellij-idea

There are 2 options when making projects in IntelliJ, if you click "Java Enterprise" at the left, you get the following options:

> JavaEE Application
>
> Web Application

What is the difference between both?

Comment: Why did you downvote this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that would be a differene between Java EE Web Profile and Full Platform - see my old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239978/java-ee-6-web-profile-vs-java-ee-6-full-platform/24240056#24240056) on this topic. However why won't you it yourself? Just create the project under each option and you will see what happens.

Comment: When I make a Java EE project, there is no web.xml and etc. There is only a src folder, so that's pretty weird? I have made both projects before, but can't figure out the difference. I can only see that the web project has a web folder incl. meta-inf & web.xml. The java ee does not have these folders.