# Is Tomcat 8 an incomplete Java EE 7 Web Profile implementation?

Tags: tomcat8, jakarta-ee

JPA 2.0 is part of the Java EE Web Profile since Java EE 6; however, it is not available in Tomcat 8.

Am I right to conclude that Tomcat 8 is, in fact, an incomplete implementation of the Java EE Web Profile?

Comment: Related Question: [*Java EE Web Profile vs Java EE Full Platform*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24239978/642706)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is not an implementation of java EE. From [Tomcat website](http://tomcat.apache.org/):

> The Apache Tomcat® software is an open source implementation of the Java Servlet, JavaServer Pages, Java Expression Language and Java WebSocket technologies.

However, [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) is:

> Apache TomEE, pronounced "Tommy", is an all-Apache Java EE 6 Web Profile certified stack where Apache Tomcat is top dog.

TomEE
The Web Profile version of TomEE contains

- CDI - Apache OpenWebBeans
- EJB - Apache OpenEJB
- JPA - Apache OpenJPA
- JSF - Apache MyFaces
- JSP - Apache Tomcat
- JSTL - Apache Tomcat
- JTA - Apache Geronimo Transaction
- Servlet - Apache Tomcat
- Javamail - Apache Geronimo JavaMail
- Bean Validation - Apache BVal

TomEE+
The TomEE Plus distribution adds the following:

- JAX-RS - Apache CXF
- JAX-WS - Apache CXF
- JMS - Apache ActiveMQ
- Connector - Apache Geronimo Connector

Comment: I see .. However, that page makes it clear what it is but doesn't say much about what it is not.

Comment: @GabrielBR I am not sure I understand your point. Tomcat is an implementation of the 4 technologies Servlet,JSP, EL and WS. Therefore, it is not an implementation of anything else :)