# Adapt Vaadin 8.5 project driven by Maven to work on Jakarta EE compliant server

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin8

What exactly must one do to take a working [Vaadin 8.5.2](https://vaadin.com/framework) app created with the [`vaadin-archetype-application`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-archetype-application) Maven archetype [provided by](https://vaadin.com/start/framework/project-base) the *Vaadin Ltd* company so that it can:

- Access the classes specified by [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee), and
- Deploy to a Jakarta EE compliant server

An example for [Glassfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) might be best, but I am curious to see any other compliant server as well.

Specifically, I want to make use of [*Concurrency Utilities 1.0 (JSR 168)*](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=166) (as [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132306/642706)) within my Vaadin web app. But my Question here is more general.

I am asking for configuration changes needed in the Maven POM. Attaching a Jarkata EE compliant server to the IDE for running-debugging is outside the scope of this Question, as that issue has likely been covered on Stack Overflow already and is not Vaadin-specific.

If this can be done with [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11) or later, and the required [modularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), so much the better.

Here is the POM created by that Maven archetype.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.basilbourque.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>trash-me-8</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>trash-me-8</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>8.5.2</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>8.5.2</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- If there are no local customizations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: My understanding is that at the moment this means that you would add Java EE 8 API depency, remove servlet API dependency (since it is redundant and already included JavaEE), and finally use Glassfish 5.1 as implementation of Java EE 8. That is more or less current state of Jakarta EE.

Answer (score 0):

To use Vaadin with Jakarta EE, you'd need the [Vaadin CDI addon](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-cdi.html) to bridge the two technologies. That is the best way to be able to use Jakarta EE as backend. You can then use any EE compatible app server.

This is from the [Vaadin project starter generator](https://vaadin.com/start/latest)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-starter-project</artifactId>
    <name>My Starter Project</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <webapp.directory>src/main/webapp</webapp.directory>

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <vaadin.version>12.0.0</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
             <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
             <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0.beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Flow uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tomeeClassifier>webprofile</tomeeClassifier>
                    <context>ROOT</context>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${webapp.directory}/frontend-es5</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${webapp.directory}/frontend-es6</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>productionMode</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>vaadin.productionMode</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <transpileOutputDirectory>${webapp.directory}</transpileOutputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

You can adapt it to suit your needs. It's based on Vaadin 12 but you can just make minor changes to get it working with 8.