# I'm using JakartaEE and making a "hello world" kind of restfulAPI, can't get a return string by visiting URL

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, rest

Providing every step I took with this short video:
https://youtu.be/hbSr8sRYuOk

Project code here: https://github.com/LJonn/restapiHelloWorld

Running everything on a local server on tomcat.

I'm having this issue for quite some time and ran out of ideas where the problem might be...
I tried URL's such as these: "http://localhost:8080/api/hello" and "http://localhost:8080/helloworld/api/hello" and expected one of these to work.

Running http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list shows that helloworld.war is deployed fine and working:
`OK - Listed applications for virtual host [localhost]`
`/:running:0:ROOT`
`/helloworld:running:0:helloworld`
`/examples:running:0:examples`
`/host-manager:running:0:host-manager`
`/manager:running:0:manager`
`/docs:running:0:docs`

So why I still get a HTTP Status 404 page? What could I try to do to find the issue?

These are my project's Maven dependencies:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Thanks to Nikos Paraskevopoulos comment it looks like changing from Tomcat to TomEE might fix the issue, but now I'm running into a problem where the .war file can't be deployed/started, probably some sort of versions compatibility issue, tomcat manager GUI gives this error when trying to start the .war file:

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/helloworld] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/helloworld]]]
```

Looking to manager logs It looks like it has something to do with annotations and Java 16 maybe?:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
        at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283)
        at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
        ... 52 more
01-Sep-2021 15:25:02.185 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

I've tried to check JRE version on Eclipse and it's 16.0.2 and it looks to me that the same version is running on tomcat.

Comment: Just a guess… Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` to avoid name resolution. Ex: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloworld` etc.

Comment: both 127.0.0.1 and localhost works the same for me. Seems like tomcat is working properly and I can access its GUI if I run it via startup.bin, but ".../api/hello" URL doesn't return a string which I expect it to do..

Comment: There are two issues I can think of: (1) you are using the `jakarta` APIs, are you sure you are using a version of Tomcat that supports it over `javax`? Please double check!!! (2) Is Tomcat supposed to pick up the JAX-RS application without an entry to the `web.xml`? Can you try again with an appropriate `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` for JAX-RS in the `web.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat 10.0 and 10.1 are **not** full Jakarta EE 9.1 application servers: you shouldn't use the `jakarta.jakartaee-web-api` artifact, which would imply that the runtime supports all Jakarta EE 9.1 [*Web Profile*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/) technologies.

Tomcat does not implement all the specs required in *Web Profile*. At least four other products do. See [this list](https://jakarta.ee/compatibility/#tab-9_1) for Jakarta Web Profile 9.1:

- Apache TomEE
- Eclipse Glassfish
- IBM Open Liberty
- Red Hat WildFly

You can find the list of supported technologies on [Tomcat's web site](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) and for Tomcat 10 they translate to this list shown as a [Maven POM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) snippet.

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.security.auth.message</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.security.auth.message-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-RC1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Since Servlet 3.0, additional Jakarta EE specifications can be added using the [servlet pluggability mechanism](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#shared-libraries-runtimes-pluggability). To use JAX-RS you need to add:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or an equivalent configuration using other JAX-RS implementations.

Comment: @LuckyTripleSmile For more details and a visual diagram, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132306/642706) on [*Java EE Web Profile vs Java EE Full Platform*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24239978/642706). Tomcat & Jetty are focused on simply being a runtime environment for servlets and JSPs. So they support only a few of the dozens of specifications defined in Jakarta EE. Mainly: HTTP web server, Servlet, JavaServer Pages (JSP), Expression Language (EL), WebSocket, JNDI, Std tag lib. Jakarta EE really should define a “profile” for what Tomcat & Jetty implement, but never have.